# Invoice Express API 500 Error

Tags: php, api, express, invoice

I'm trying to use the invoice express api to create new invoice on my account and it keeps throwing me a 500 error as the result of that api call.

My code is:

```
    <?php
include_once('../libraries/spyc.php');
$APP_CONFIG = spyc_load_file('../libraries/config.yaml');

$screenname = $APP_CONFIG['screen_name'];
$api_key = $APP_CONFIG['api_key'];
$host = $APP_CONFIG['host'];

ob_start(); 
$db = new mysqli('localhost', 'user' , 'pass', 'db');
$id = $_GET['id'];
$result = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT * FROM orders WHERE id = '".$id."'");
$value = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

$date = date("d/m/Y", strtotime($value['post_date']));


$invoice_data = '
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <invoice>
   <date>' . $date . '<date>
   <due_date>' . $date . '</due_date>
   <reference>25381g</reference>
   <observations>0</observations>
   <retention>0</retention>
   <client>
    <name>XX Bruce Norris</name>
    <email>foo@ar.com</email>
    <address>Badgad</address>
    <postal_code>120213920139</postal_code>
    <country>Germany</country>
    <fiscal_id>12</fiscal_id>
    <website> h</website>
    <phone>2313423424</phone>
    <fax>0</fax>
    <observations> 0</observations>
   </client>
   <items type="array">
    <item>
     <name>Product 1</name>
     <description>Cleaning product</description>
     <unit_price>10.0</unit_price>
     <quantity>1.0</quantity>
     <unit>unit</unit>
      <tax>
        <name>IVA23</name>
      </tax>
     <discount>10.0</discount>
    </item>
   </items>
  </invoice>';



$endpoint = "https://".$screenname.".".$host."/invoices.xml?api_key=".$api_key;


// Initialize handle and set options
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $endpoint);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 4);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $invoice_data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/xml'));

// Execute the request
$result_invoice = curl_exec($ch);
// Close the handle
curl_close($ch);

echo $result_invoice;
```

I know it's not a problem with the db access because I have tested that and the query itself and it came back perfectly.

I have also tried setting error reporting to E_ALL and display errors but I still only get a 500 error on the webpage.

Comment: Go have a look in your web server's error log. The 500 will be fleshed out with more detail there. In PHP you can crank up error reporting by adding `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` to the top of your script. Always recommended to use `display_errors` in development.

Comment: You can also try to execute `php -l file.php` if you use php_cli.

Comment: Unfortunately I have tried setting those values in the beginning of my file but all I get is still a 500 error, I will update my question.
Can't really use Php_cli as well but thank you both

Answer (score 1):

I had come across the very same 500 Error and then I recognize that, my error is in the URL. 
https://screen-name.invoicexpress.net/invoices.xml

Then I happen to go via http://invoicexpress.com/api/users/login , which returns me the "screen-name" part of the URL.

Make sure $screenname is of yours, it helps me to get rid of 500 Error.